# How to implement liveness/readines using springboot 2.3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

I recently learned that springboot 2.3.0 offers liveness/readiness. In order to implement them, I updated springboot version to 2.3.0 and added dependency spring-boot-starter-validation in pom. I updated helm chart's env section as well to contain:

```
  name: management.health.probes.enabled
  value: 'true'
  name: management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include
  value: 'readinessState,db'
```

Is this all I need to in order to implement liveness and readiness probes for the component? If so, is there way to test this locally? My co-worker told me if I can write environment locally in application.properties, I should be able to test it locally (running postman and expose api such as /actuator/health/livness or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add actuator dependency in pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

HTTP Probes are only configured for applications running on Kubernetes. You can give it a try locally by manually enabling the probes with the `management.health.probes.enabled=true` configuration property

You can check the liveness and readiness by curl or using postman to hit below endpoints

```
// http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/liveness
// HTTP/1.1 200 OK

{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
    "livenessProbe": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}

// http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/readiness
// HTTP/1.1 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE

{
  "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE",
  "components": {
    "readinessProbe": {
      "status": "OUT_OF_SERVICE"
    }
  }
}
```

You can of course configure additional Health Indicators to be part of the Probes, checking for the state of external systems: a database, a Web API, a shared cache.

```
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=livenessProbe,customCheck
```

Comment: Awesome. For local testing, I added `management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=readinessProbe,db` and `management.health.probes.enabled=true` and also database url, username and password. It works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This works! I just have a question. When I call localhost:8080/actuator/health, I am expecting it to give me liveness and readiness, including db. But I am not getting any of these (just status). Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you seeing similar to what is here https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot

Comment: I am only seeing these: {
    "status": "DOWN",
    "groups": [
        "liveness",
        "readiness"
    ]
}. When I do them separately, they work fine.